# Creating seaborn stripplot in Stata

Tags: plot, stata, strip

I would like to replicate the attached picture of a seaborn strip plot in Stata.

I would like  the differences between males and females to be clear according to each age group.

How to:

- create two separate boxes (one for male, one for female) according to each age group
- place the data points within the boxes

[seaborn stripplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQO4C.png)

My current figure
[need to modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyXZv.png)

```
stripplot igg1ugml_log10, separate(female_sex) over(age_groups) vertical stack  ///
box(barw(0.3) bfc(none)) ///
iqr boffset(-0.1) mc(blue) ms(dh) jitter(2)
```

I have done this with box plots but I believe stripplots would be more useful as it would show each individual data point.
[example of previous box plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL7uk.png)

data example:

```
clear
input studyid igg1ugml_log10 age_groups female_sex
EPIC-282    3.589394    Newborns    Females
EPIC-052    3.601804    Newborns    Males
EPIC-216    3.661577    Newborns    Males
EPIC-385    3.18681 Newborns    Males
EPIC-380    3.491205    Newborns    Females
EPIC-383    3.514449    Newborns    Males
EPIC-222    3.574592    Newborns    Females
EPIC-384    3.592241    Newborns    Males
EPIC-319    3.488404    Newborns    Females
EPIC-099    3.540483    Newborns    Females
EPIC-321    3.313488    Infants Males
EPIC-343    3.633899    Infants Females
EPIC-197    3.36994 Infants Males
EPIC-390    2.987238    Infants Males
EPIC-326    3.484874    Infants Males
EPIC-381    2.94206 Infants Males
EPIC-379    2.77069 Infants Females
EPIC-388    2.868036    Infants Males
EPIC-313    3.072073    Infants Males
EPIC-360    3.234904    Infants Males
EPIC-364    3.108388    Infants Females
EPIC-324    3.268844    Infants Females
EPIC-391    3.142118    Infants Males
EPIC-063    3.777336    Infants Females
EPIC-295    3.362673    Infants Males
EPIC-271    3.222235    Infants Females
EPIC-077    3.160751    Infants Males
EPIC-177    3.540396    Infants Males
EPIC-029        Infants Females
EPIC-339    2.993336    Infants Males
EPIC-155    2.736377    Infants Females
EPIC-003    3.77974 Infants Males
EPIC-386    3.498877    Infants Females
EPIC-387    3.274867    Infants Males
EPIC-079    3.46829 Infants Females
EPIC-249    3.021762    Infants Males
EPIC-262    3.47287 Toddlers    Females
EPIC-014    3.702181    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-060    3.727462    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-124    3.691641    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-163    3.950433    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-141    3.685666    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-088    3.64166 Toddlers    Males
EPIC-243    3.538419    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-011    3.640694    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-074    3.586019    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-270    3.636692    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-359    3.850905    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-136    3.769435    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-332    3.768998    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-158    3.445705    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-133    3.866579    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-091    3.628281    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-159    3.743297    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-179    3.582957    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-106    3.613727    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-150    3.508947    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-161    3.697679    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-240    3.61907 Toddlers    Males
EPIC-232    3.635148    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-263    3.627222    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-033    3.397326    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-075    3.47438 Toddlers    Females
EPIC-148    3.290431    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-044    3.623537    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-059    3.636081    Toddlers    Females
EPIC-167    3.674943    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-303    3.450586    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-157    3.667369    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-224    3.454268    Toddlers    Males
EPIC-225    3.796839    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-182    3.844481    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-082    3.714746    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-269    3.576113    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-215    3.500583    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-055    3.542279    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-283    3.604445    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-257    3.650505    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-201    3.693031    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-279    3.734797    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-068    3.786582    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-292    3.612626    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-004    3.79031 Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-001    3.816278    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-097    3.662127    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-192    3.761757    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-038    3.550861    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-198    3.421037    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-149    3.601083    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-047    3.817248    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-274    3.520943    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-223    3.789712    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-338    3.518501    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-135    3.525718    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-170    3.781471    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-334    3.721625    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-160    3.730618    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-299    3.844734    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-310    3.481133    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-340    3.704354    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-272    3.672922    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-301    3.468832    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-370    3.828788    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-130    3.556107    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-005    3.49684 Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-281    3.721865    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-373    3.74819 Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-189    3.741195    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-256    3.640121    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-139    3.64257 Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-100    3.590413    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-181    3.741408    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-273    3.472844    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-008    3.644366    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-206    3.597543    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-019    3.52022 Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-297    3.611279    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-049    3.778106    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-132    3.549588    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-368    3.742799    Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-220    2.957175    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-067    3.710578    Pre-schoolers   Males
EPIC-078    3.55196 Pre-schoolers   Females
EPIC-204    3.805212    School-agers    Females
EPIC-057    3.459229    School-agers    Males
EPIC-259    3.381808    School-agers    Males
EPIC-016    3.59847 School-agers    Females
EPIC-006    3.680997    School-agers    Males
EPIC-300    3.63776 School-agers    Females
EPIC-196    3.683982    School-agers    Females
EPIC-331    3.523625    School-agers    Males
EPIC-127    3.65398 School-agers    Females
EPIC-147    3.716885    School-agers    Females
EPIC-108    3.334462    School-agers    Males
EPIC-176    3.712171    School-agers    Males
EPIC-336    3.616541    School-agers    Males
EPIC-294    3.634205    School-agers    Males
EPIC-095    3.523943    School-agers    Females
EPIC-251    3.642459    School-agers    Females
EPIC-355    3.636979    School-agers    Females
EPIC-174    3.580813    School-agers    Females
EPIC-035    3.5104  School-agers    Males
EPIC-236    3.553553    School-agers    Females
EPIC-376    3.598671    School-agers    Males
EPIC-188    3.629169    School-agers    Males
EPIC-245    3.583945    School-agers    Males
EPIC-327    3.830761    School-agers    Females
EPIC-109    3.620162    School-agers    Males
EPIC-028    3.592769    School-agers    Males
EPIC-073    3.766612    School-agers    Females
EPIC-041    3.882484    School-agers    Females
EPIC-361    3.727022    School-agers    Males
EPIC-258    3.780413    School-agers    Males
EPIC-061    3.64599 School-agers    Males
EPIC-306    3.713696    School-agers    Females
EPIC-183    3.698176    School-agers    Males
EPIC-184    3.588534    School-agers    Males
EPIC-330    3.707305    School-agers    Females
EPIC-226    3.507428    School-agers    Males
EPIC-217    3.604447    School-agers    Males
EPIC-152    3.423132    School-agers    Females
EPIC-307    3.525626    School-agers    Females
EPIC-278    3.584807    School-agers    Males
EPIC-372    3.670738    School-agers    Males
EPIC-119    3.453463    School-agers    Females
EPIC-031    3.584172    School-agers    Females
EPIC-043    3.18681 School-agers    Females
EPIC-275    3.66261 School-agers    Females
EPIC-069    3.676336    School-agers    Females
EPIC-305    3.747393    School-agers    Males
EPIC-083    3.552132    School-agers    Males
EPIC-156    3.833339    School-agers    Females
EPIC-104    3.84757 School-agers    Females
EPIC-134    3.569256    School-agers    Females
EPIC-320    3.534669    School-agers    Males
EPIC-076    3.492767    School-agers    Females
EPIC-165    3.58931 School-agers    Males
EPIC-252    3.670954    School-agers    Females
EPIC-199    3.601526    School-agers    Females
EPIC-221    3.678435    School-agers    Females
EPIC-137    3.748554    School-agers    Females
EPIC-065    3.655474    School-agers    Females
EPIC-085    3.850893    School-agers    Females
EPIC-191    3.694109    School-agers    Females
EPIC-311    3.514497    School-agers    Females
EPIC-314    3.665684    School-agers    Females
EPIC-212    3.746262    School-agers    Females
EPIC-208    3.516045    School-agers    Males
EPIC-146    3.48094 School-agers    Males
EPIC-287    3.732855    School-agers    Females
EPIC-254    3.419544    School-agers    Females
EPIC-309    3.498083    School-agers    Females
EPIC-145    3.706506    School-agers    Males
EPIC-071    3.722446    School-agers    Males
EPIC-101    3.601708    School-agers    Females
EPIC-242    3.666782    School-agers    Males
EPIC-248    3.67726 School-agers    Females
EPIC-020    3.772248    School-agers    Females
EPIC-363    3.658555    School-agers    Males
EPIC-365    3.97472 School-agers    Females
EPIC-260    3.776132    School-agers    Males
EPIC-023    3.888149    School-agers    Males
EPIC-009    3.595163    School-agers    Females
EPIC-233    3.63002 School-agers    Females
EPIC-129    3.666271    School-agers    Males
EPIC-218    3.604407    School-agers    Females
EPIC-341    3.692122    School-agers    Males
EPIC-205    3.606836    School-agers    Males
EPIC-296    3.520653    School-agers    Males
EPIC-375    3.599961    School-agers    Males
EPIC-111    3.372121    School-agers    Females
EPIC-203    3.701799    School-agers    Females
EPIC-151    3.005775    School-agers    Males
EPIC-166    3.706154    School-agers    Females
EPIC-231    3.665022    School-agers    Males
EPIC-118    3.59145 School-agers    Males
EPIC-353    3.657591    School-agers    Males
EPIC-138    3.660277    School-agers    Males
EPIC-345    3.646935    School-agers    Males
EPIC-298    3.73373 School-agers    Females
EPIC-173    3.771135    School-agers    Males
EPIC-117    3.581085    School-agers    Females
EPIC-244    3.619419    School-agers    Males
EPIC-084    3.63121 School-agers    Males
EPIC-030    3.757021    Adolescents Males
EPIC-169    3.614358    Adolescents Females
EPIC-277    3.596717    Adolescents Females
EPIC-357    3.609617    Adolescents Males
EPIC-144    3.713401    Adolescents Males
EPIC-054    3.590533    Adolescents Females
EPIC-062    3.775664    Adolescents Females
EPIC-116    3.713848    Adolescents Females
EPIC-290    3.37809 Adolescents Males
EPIC-105    3.63936 Adolescents Females
EPIC-131    3.713675    Adolescents Females
EPIC-045    3.725061    Adolescents Females
EPIC-238    3.689295    Adolescents Males
EPIC-140    3.591715    Adolescents Females
EPIC-171    3.6907  Adolescents Females
EPIC-086    3.608863    Adolescents Females
EPIC-347    3.335269    Adolescents Females
EPIC-089    3.633344    Adolescents Females
EPIC-143    3.258598    Adolescents Males
EPIC-229    3.6234  Adolescents Males
EPIC-050    3.664356    Adolescents Females
EPIC-048    3.670372    Adolescents Males
EPIC-122    3.53829 Adolescents Females
EPIC-266    3.554435    Adolescents Males
EPIC-153    3.596575    Adolescents Females
EPIC-200    3.601564    Adolescents Males
EPIC-039    3.681573    Adolescents Males
EPIC-213    3.640994    Adolescents Males
EPIC-202    3.677024    Adolescents Males
EPIC-102    3.750609    Adolescents Females
EPIC-154    3.575089    Adolescents Males
EPIC-186    3.488832    Adolescents Males
EPIC-021    3.799192    Adolescents Males
EPIC-025    3.729567    Adolescents Females
EPIC-214    3.733021    Adolescents Males
EPIC-237    3.510419    Adolescents Females
EPIC-247    3.486355    Adolescents Females
EPIC-168    3.834998    Adolescents Females
EPIC-211    3.70257 Adolescents Males
EPIC-356    3.612938    Adolescents Males
EPIC-346    3.551227    Adolescents Males
EPIC-350    3.742462    Adolescents Females
EPIC-090    3.688402    Adolescents Females
EPIC-317    3.506298    Adolescents Males
EPIC-142    3.599556    Adolescents Females
EPIC-328    3.591878    Adolescents Females
EPIC-284    3.343338    Adolescents Females
EPIC-066    3.672521    Adolescents Females
EPIC-013    3.675033    Adolescents Males
EPIC-194    3.597242    Adolescents Females
EPIC-027    3.443944    Adolescents Females
EPIC-286    3.835772    Adolescents Males
EPIC-348    3.647459    Adolescents Males
EPIC-096    3.634818    Adolescents Females
EPIC-193    3.523559    Adolescents Females
EPIC-040    3.712117    Adolescents Females
EPIC-344    3.592488    Adolescents Females
EPIC-234    3.834983    Adolescents Females
EPIC-058    3.493379    Adolescents Females
EPIC-337    3.507127    Adolescents Males
EPIC-007    3.622676    Adolescents Females
EPIC-354    3.615168    Adolescents Males
EPIC-235    3.618872    Adolescents Males
EPIC-246    3.718265    Adolescents Males
EPIC-018    3.649301    Adolescents Females
EPIC-318    3.660334    Adolescents Females
EPIC-175    3.791891    Adolescents Males
EPIC-125    3.163378    Adolescents Females
EPIC-315    3.509594    Adolescents Males
EPIC-371    3.506503    Adolescents Males
EPIC-329    3.619459    Adolescents Females
EPIC-026    3.728787    Adolescents Females
EPIC-022    3.573861    Adolescents Males
EPIC-002    3.589432    Adolescents Females
EPIC-335    3.593705    Adolescents Males
EPIC-239    3.704319    Adolescents Males
EPIC-046    3.703688    Adolescents Females
EPIC-264    3.738565    Adolescents Males
EPIC-366    3.871413    Adolescents Males
EPIC-112    3.578247    Adolescents Females
EPIC-219    3.883983    Adolescents Females
EPIC-094    3.686223    Adolescents Males
EPIC-312    3.683946    Adolescents Males
EPIC-164    3.854109    Adolescents Females
EPIC-034    3.410698    Adolescents Females
EPIC-265    3.645107    Adolescents Males
EPIC-080    3.57388 Adolescents Females
EPIC-087    3.515841    Adolescents Females
EPIC-267    3.539299    Adolescents Males
EPIC-114    3.840031    Adolescents Males
EPIC-308    3.84687 Adolescents Males
EPIC-362    3.666621    Adolescents Males
EPIC-369    3.701343    Adolescents Females
EPIC-128    3.668065    Adolescents Males
EPIC-253    3.460822    Adolescents Males
EPIC-291    3.633324    Adolescents Males
EPIC-250    3.625359    Adolescents Females
EPIC-037    3.686401    Adolescents Females
EPIC-042    3.475209    Adolescents Males
EPIC-162    3.634129    Adolescents Males
EPIC-051    3.644157    Adolescents Females
EPIC-178    3.710834    Adolescents Males
EPIC-227    3.495148    Adolescents Males
EPIC-012    3.67145 Adolescents Males
EPIC-064    3.579015    Adolescents Females
EPIC-081    3.648888    Adolescents Females
EPIC-070    3.781692    Adolescents Males
EPIC-207    3.762642    Adolescents Males
EPIC-113    3.751701    Adolescents Males
EPIC-316    3.610844    Adolescents Males
end
```

march 24 updated stripplot based on nicks comments
[image: stripplot update]

Comment: i have added the data example. if it is not appearing correctly here, i have also added it to the following link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vt94-a6XOkFzPvLRXpQwS6t4hwc5ebk0yV_v2Be6j3M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the data example. That's not code that would run as the `input` command will choke on the strings. We can work around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version of your data, with guesses at the order of your age categories. As you've presented them, they would just be ordered alphabetically as strings.

`stripplot` from SSC is my program and I've got prejudices about its use. It will support jittering but I think that is a poor way to show data. With this version the points are ordered in a version of a quantile-box plot.

In a previous answer I explained to you how to show the mu of microgram properly. ug is a poor approximation.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str50 studyid double igg1ugml_log10 str13 age_groups str10 female_sex
"EPIC-282" 3.589394 "Newborns"      "Females"
"EPIC-052" 3.601804 "Newborns"      "Males"  
"EPIC-216" 3.661577 "Newborns"      "Males"  
"EPIC-385"  3.18681 "Newborns"      "Males"  
"EPIC-380" 3.491205 "Newborns"      "Females"
"EPIC-383" 3.514449 "Newborns"      "Males"  
"EPIC-222" 3.574592 "Newborns"      "Females"
"EPIC-384" 3.592241 "Newborns"      "Males"  
"EPIC-319" 3.488404 "Newborns"      "Females"
"EPIC-099" 3.540483 "Newborns"      "Females"
"EPIC-321" 3.313488 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-343" 3.633899 "Infants"       "Females"
"EPIC-197"  3.36994 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-390" 2.987238 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-326" 3.484874 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-381"  2.94206 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-379"  2.77069 "Infants"       "Females"
"EPIC-388" 2.868036 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-313" 3.072073 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-360" 3.234904 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-364" 3.108388 "Infants"       "Females"
"EPIC-324" 3.268844 "Infants"       "Females"
"EPIC-391" 3.142118 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-063" 3.777336 "Infants"       "Females"
"EPIC-295" 3.362673 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-271" 3.222235 "Infants"       "Females"
"EPIC-077" 3.160751 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-177" 3.540396 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-029"        . "Infants"       "Females"
"EPIC-339" 2.993336 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-155" 2.736377 "Infants"       "Females"
"EPIC-003"  3.77974 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-386" 3.498877 "Infants"       "Females"
"EPIC-387" 3.274867 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-079"  3.46829 "Infants"       "Females"
"EPIC-249" 3.021762 "Infants"       "Males"  
"EPIC-262"  3.47287 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-014" 3.702181 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-060" 3.727462 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-124" 3.691641 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-163" 3.950433 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-141" 3.685666 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-088"  3.64166 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-243" 3.538419 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-011" 3.640694 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-074" 3.586019 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-270" 3.636692 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-359" 3.850905 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-136" 3.769435 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-332" 3.768998 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-158" 3.445705 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-133" 3.866579 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-091" 3.628281 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-159" 3.743297 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-179" 3.582957 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-106" 3.613727 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-150" 3.508947 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-161" 3.697679 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-240"  3.61907 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-232" 3.635148 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-263" 3.627222 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-033" 3.397326 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-075"  3.47438 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-148" 3.290431 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-044" 3.623537 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-059" 3.636081 "Toddlers"      "Females"
"EPIC-167" 3.674943 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-303" 3.450586 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-157" 3.667369 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-224" 3.454268 "Toddlers"      "Males"  
"EPIC-225" 3.796839 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-182" 3.844481 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-082" 3.714746 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-269" 3.576113 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-215" 3.500583 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-055" 3.542279 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-283" 3.604445 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-257" 3.650505 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-201" 3.693031 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-279" 3.734797 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-068" 3.786582 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-292" 3.612626 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-004"  3.79031 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-001" 3.816278 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-097" 3.662127 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-192" 3.761757 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-038" 3.550861 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-198" 3.421037 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-149" 3.601083 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-047" 3.817248 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-274" 3.520943 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-223" 3.789712 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-338" 3.518501 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-135" 3.525718 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-170" 3.781471 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-334" 3.721625 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-160" 3.730618 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-299" 3.844734 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-310" 3.481133 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-340" 3.704354 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-272" 3.672922 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-301" 3.468832 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-370" 3.828788 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-130" 3.556107 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-005"  3.49684 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-281" 3.721865 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-373"  3.74819 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-189" 3.741195 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-256" 3.640121 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-139"  3.64257 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-100" 3.590413 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-181" 3.741408 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-273" 3.472844 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-008" 3.644366 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-206" 3.597543 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-019"  3.52022 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-297" 3.611279 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-049" 3.778106 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-132" 3.549588 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-368" 3.742799 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-220" 2.957175 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-067" 3.710578 "Pre-schoolers" "Males"  
"EPIC-078"  3.55196 "Pre-schoolers" "Females"
"EPIC-204" 3.805212 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-057" 3.459229 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-259" 3.381808 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-016"  3.59847 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-006" 3.680997 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-300"  3.63776 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-196" 3.683982 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-331" 3.523625 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-127"  3.65398 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-147" 3.716885 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-108" 3.334462 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-176" 3.712171 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-336" 3.616541 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-294" 3.634205 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-095" 3.523943 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-251" 3.642459 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-355" 3.636979 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-174" 3.580813 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-035"   3.5104 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-236" 3.553553 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-376" 3.598671 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-188" 3.629169 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-245" 3.583945 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-327" 3.830761 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-109" 3.620162 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-028" 3.592769 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-073" 3.766612 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-041" 3.882484 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-361" 3.727022 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-258" 3.780413 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-061"  3.64599 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-306" 3.713696 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-183" 3.698176 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-184" 3.588534 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-330" 3.707305 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-226" 3.507428 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-217" 3.604447 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-152" 3.423132 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-307" 3.525626 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-278" 3.584807 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-372" 3.670738 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-119" 3.453463 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-031" 3.584172 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-043"  3.18681 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-275"  3.66261 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-069" 3.676336 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-305" 3.747393 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-083" 3.552132 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-156" 3.833339 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-104"  3.84757 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-134" 3.569256 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-320" 3.534669 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-076" 3.492767 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-165"  3.58931 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-252" 3.670954 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-199" 3.601526 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-221" 3.678435 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-137" 3.748554 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-065" 3.655474 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-085" 3.850893 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-191" 3.694109 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-311" 3.514497 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-314" 3.665684 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-212" 3.746262 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-208" 3.516045 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-146"  3.48094 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-287" 3.732855 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-254" 3.419544 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-309" 3.498083 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-145" 3.706506 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-071" 3.722446 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-101" 3.601708 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-242" 3.666782 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-248"  3.67726 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-020" 3.772248 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-363" 3.658555 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-365"  3.97472 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-260" 3.776132 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-023" 3.888149 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-009" 3.595163 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-233"  3.63002 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-129" 3.666271 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-218" 3.604407 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-341" 3.692122 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-205" 3.606836 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-296" 3.520653 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-375" 3.599961 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-111" 3.372121 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-203" 3.701799 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-151" 3.005775 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-166" 3.706154 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-231" 3.665022 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-118"  3.59145 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-353" 3.657591 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-138" 3.660277 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-345" 3.646935 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-298"  3.73373 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-173" 3.771135 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-117" 3.581085 "School-agers"  "Females"
"EPIC-244" 3.619419 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-084"  3.63121 "School-agers"  "Males"  
"EPIC-030" 3.757021 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-169" 3.614358 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-277" 3.596717 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-357" 3.609617 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-144" 3.713401 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-054" 3.590533 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-062" 3.775664 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-116" 3.713848 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-290"  3.37809 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-105"  3.63936 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-131" 3.713675 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-045" 3.725061 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-238" 3.689295 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-140" 3.591715 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-171"   3.6907 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-086" 3.608863 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-347" 3.335269 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-089" 3.633344 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-143" 3.258598 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-229"   3.6234 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-050" 3.664356 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-048" 3.670372 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-122"  3.53829 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-266" 3.554435 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-153" 3.596575 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-200" 3.601564 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-039" 3.681573 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-213" 3.640994 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-202" 3.677024 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-102" 3.750609 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-154" 3.575089 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-186" 3.488832 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-021" 3.799192 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-025" 3.729567 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-214" 3.733021 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-237" 3.510419 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-247" 3.486355 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-168" 3.834998 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-211"  3.70257 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-356" 3.612938 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-346" 3.551227 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-350" 3.742462 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-090" 3.688402 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-317" 3.506298 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-142" 3.599556 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-328" 3.591878 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-284" 3.343338 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-066" 3.672521 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-013" 3.675033 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-194" 3.597242 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-027" 3.443944 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-286" 3.835772 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-348" 3.647459 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-096" 3.634818 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-193" 3.523559 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-040" 3.712117 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-344" 3.592488 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-234" 3.834983 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-058" 3.493379 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-337" 3.507127 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-007" 3.622676 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-354" 3.615168 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-235" 3.618872 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-246" 3.718265 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-018" 3.649301 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-318" 3.660334 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-175" 3.791891 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-125" 3.163378 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-315" 3.509594 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-371" 3.506503 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-329" 3.619459 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-026" 3.728787 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-022" 3.573861 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-002" 3.589432 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-335" 3.593705 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-239" 3.704319 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-046" 3.703688 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-264" 3.738565 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-366" 3.871413 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-112" 3.578247 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-219" 3.883983 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-094" 3.686223 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-312" 3.683946 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-164" 3.854109 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-034" 3.410698 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-265" 3.645107 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-080"  3.57388 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-087" 3.515841 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-267" 3.539299 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-114" 3.840031 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-308"  3.84687 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-362" 3.666621 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-369" 3.701343 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-128" 3.668065 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-253" 3.460822 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-291" 3.633324 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-250" 3.625359 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-037" 3.686401 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-042" 3.475209 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-162" 3.634129 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-051" 3.644157 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-178" 3.710834 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-227" 3.495148 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-012"  3.67145 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-064" 3.579015 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-081" 3.648888 "Adolescents"   "Females"
"EPIC-070" 3.781692 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-207" 3.762642 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-113" 3.751701 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
"EPIC-316" 3.610844 "Adolescents"   "Males"  
end

label def age 1 Newborns 2 Infants 3 Toddlers 4 "Pre-schoolers" 5 "School-agers" 6 Adolescents
encode age_groups, gen(age) label(age)

stripplot igg, over(female_sex) by(age, legend(off) row(1) compact note("")) box(barw(1) blc(gs12))  ///
vertical mc(orange_red blue) ms(oh oh) scheme(s1color) centre cumul cumprob xtitle("") ///
yla(2.8(0.2)4, ang(h)) xla(, labsize(small)) xsize(7) separate(female)
```

[image]

Comment: do you think a violin plot would show the data better?

how to bring age groups from the top of the graph to the bottom? 
and remove "males" "females" at the bottom? will include male/female as legend as part of the final figure 
I have shown the updated figure based on your comments

Comment: These aren't all programming questions. Violin plots are in my view oversold but regardless of that couldn't do justice to this data set: some of the subsamples are very small and it's important to see outliers in context. The handle for more rows is explicit in the syntax. Similarly you can delete `legend(off)` and suppress the horizontal axis labels as general Stata graphics choices, but i recommend otherwise.

Comment: another question if you don't mind, how do you remove the black lines from inside the graph but keep the black surrounding the whole graph?